# Html Input type="file" : Issue in some mobile devices : files are shown but their selection are disabled

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using **HTML** `input type = "file" in an IONIC/Cordova Project.`
It works fine in some devices , but in some devices ,it presents me with this **issue :**

```
The file picker is opened and I am able to browse files,
but their selection is disabled.
Searched for a solution but couldn't find any.
Any help is really appreciated.
```

**Here is the code snippet:**

```
input type="file" accept=".pdf,image/*"  ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" id="file"
```

Comment: Can you let us know which devices it  isn't working for?

Comment: In addition to @Fencer04's question, could you provide more detail on what types of files are selectable? What happens when you try to select?

Comment: I believe there is issue in android kitkat  4.4 for cordova file input .

Comment: @Fencer04
it does not works for marshmallow and few kitkat and lollipop devices.
I havent found any partcular device or OS versions

@ Adam
When it works, all files are selectable.
But when it doesn't , files are disabled (faded out)

Comment: @AliEsmaeili   yes it seems so

Comment: Anyways trying to use Cordova Plugin FileChooser and it works fine...
Thanks for your help :)